# Exporting entire bbox from overpass turbo?

Tags: openstreetmap, extents, overpass-api

I'm trying to export all the elements (peak, tracks, routes, streets.....) of a bounding box I have selected.

I'm trying to do this with the wizard, but within it, I have to choose specific tags and so export one element per each time, right?

Comment: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide#All_data_in_a_bounding_box should guide you to the correct syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To copy from the [documentation](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide#Sample_map_calls), `(node(50.746,7.154,50.748,7.157); <;); out meta;` (replace numbers with `lat_min`, `lon_min`, `lat_max`, `lon_max` for your query) to get all the features for a bounding box. Note that the amount of data returned can be very, very large. If you need an entire dataset for a administrative region or a whole country, you better off using [regional extracts](http://download.geofabrik.de/).